# Set Landing page to billing in paypal adaptive payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I need help regarding the landing page when we use the paypal adaptive payment.
I read about the landing page variable but I am unable to use that variable.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp0em.png)

Answer (score 0):

Landing Page =Billing only available for Express Checkout. Adaptive Payment is another API which the usage of landing page will be ignored or triggered an error.Have you finish integrate Adaptive Payment? By right the option of guest checkout (pay with CC) will be shown as default together with Pay with PayPal.

Comment: Thanks for reply. For now, i skip the landing page  functionality in  case of paypal adaptive payments.